# string inside string inside string in python format

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to put string inside string inside string like below

```
f"{home.select_one('td a[title="Odds"]')['href']}"
```

but it return error

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Which is the variable name?

Comment: Use triple quotes.

Comment: variable name : home

Comment: I have answered in the original thread @Ravanelli

Answer (score 0):

Escape the quotes:

```
print("{home.select_one('td a[title=\"Odds\"]')['href']}")
```

Comment: SyntaxError: f-string expression part cannot include a backslash

Comment: I didn't mention about f-strings, this is for general and raw strings

Comment: @Ravanelli: not it does not. The line supplied by Wasif works. Therefore, you are doing something else.

Answer (score 0):

Use  `.format`

```
In [117]: home = BeautifulSoup("""<td><a title="Odds" href="https://url"></td>""", "html.parser")

In [118]: "{}".format(home.select_one('td a[title=\"Odds\"]')['href'])
Out[118]: 'https://url'
```

Or use triple quotes

```
In [123]: f"""
     ...: {home.select_one('td a[title="Odds"]')['href']}
     ...:
     ...: """.strip()
Out[123]: 'https://url'
```